# C# Program want to select data <= 23:59:59 but ends up selecting data with 00:00:00 timestamp as well

Tags: c#, sql-server

this is my first question so pardon any mistakes that might occurs :)

I made a C# program that collects data from SQL Server Database using Datatables, and then export the results to Excel spreadsheets using Interop.
The program itself runs well and doing as it should; however, I found some bugs when it tries to select data with `Date` columns less than or equal to i.e. `2014-05-31 23:59:59`.

Supposed I tried to get all data up to May 1st 2014.

My code first initiates the "Start Date" parameter for the SQL Command later used like this:

```
var firstDay = new DateTime(today.Year, today.Month, 1); //2014-05-01 00:00:00`
```

based on `firstDay`, it initiates the date for the parameter

```
var periodTo = firstDay.AddSeconds(-1);`
```

I debugged and got the time I wanted: `2014-04-30 23:59:59`

After adding some more parameters for the data criteria, it executes the method to run the query using the parameters supplied.

```
queryResult = medicore.GenerateRegister(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queryDir"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["queryName"]);`
```

The `periodTo` parameter will be mapped to `@EDate` variable in the SQL Script. `@EDate` is declared as `Datetime`. The `@Edate` comes into play here:

```
Select columns
From tables
Where Voucher.Date <= @EDate
```

which I suppose, the script will be looks like `Where Voucher.Date <= '2014-04-30 23:59:59'`

The problem is, the result in the Excel file generated also consists of data from `'2014-05-01'`, which is not supposed to be there...at least based on the criteria I set.

Is there some kind of rounding happened between C# and SQL Server?

Thanks!

Comment: You need to provide code that reproduces the problem, a query with `WHERE Voucher.Date <= @EDate` where `@Edate` is '2014-04-30 23:59:59' is not going to return records where `Voucher.Date = 2014-05-01` so there is probably something else going on here.

Comment: @BenRobinson it was due to `Date` column being `smalldatetime` format, as @GarethD mentioned....the query scripts was legacy, and I developed programs to automate that using the scripts, so...oh well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this is probably that `Voucher.Date` is a `SMALLDATETIME`, therefore you are implicitly converting `'2014-04-30 23:59:59'` to a `SMALLDATETIME`:

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;
SELECT  CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '2014-04-30 23:59:59')
```

Which gives '2014-05-01'.

Why not just use the Less than operator, instead of less than or equal to?

```
SET DATEFORMAT MDY;

SELECT  ...
WHERE   Voucher.Date < '2014-05-01';
```

N.B I have explcilty stated the `DATEFORMAT` because `yyyy-MM-dd` (despite being an ISO standard) is not culture invariant for the `DATETIME` and `SMALLDATETIME` data types in SQL Server, and if (like me) you are in a country where the default date format is `DMY` then `SELECT CONVERT(SMALLDATETIME, '2014-04-30')` will give you a conversion error. `yyyyMMdd` is the **only** culture invariant date format for these two types.

An excellent, and very relevant article to read is Aaron Bertrand's [Bad habits to kick : mis-handling date / range queries](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/16/bad-habits-to-kick-mis-handling-date-range-queries)

Comment: oh my God. I cannot believe the answer was that simple: `smalldatetime`

screw this legacy query scripts.....

anyway...thanks for the insights. Truly a wake-up call on how you can't overlook such mistakes...